# Cannot access dataset value correctly: Angular

Tags: angular

First time posting, sorry for inconvenience.

So, I've this angular application where I'm getting some data from my backend **(successfully)**.
And using it in the template of my component.
*Directive placed on `line 9`*

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 w-100">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="day">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Day</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element?.day}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <div
                [attr.data-status]="element?.status"
                appSetStatus
                class="outer-circle"
            >
                <div class="inner-circle"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
</table>
```

The thing when I log the element on which the `directive` is placed, it prints the html element with correct dataset correct assigned value. But on printing the value itself it results in `null`.

```js
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[appSetStatus]"
})
export class SetStatusDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement);
        console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement.getAttribute("data-status"));
        // OR
        console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement.dataset.status);
    }
}
```

### Output

```html
<div appsetstatus class="outer-circle" data-status="on">...</div>
null undefined
```

```html
<div appsetstatus class="outer-circle" data-status="none">...</div>
null undefined
```

```html
<div appsetstatus class="outer-circle" data-status="none">...</div>
null undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing as an attribute, you can pass it as @Input

**Template:**

```
<div [appSetStatus]="element?.status" class="outer-circle">
```

**Directive:**

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[appSetStatus]"
})
export class SetStatusDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    @Input()
    set appSetStatus(value: any){
      console.log(value);
    }
}
```